# Did House Reed pledge for House Stark When Jon Snow as "King in the north" already claimed the North?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As we know that Ned Stark and Howland Reed are good friends. I haven't seen them on the picture pledging or fighting for house stark, Only about Meera and Jojen accompanying Bran Stark for a mission.

Comment: [Relevant: Where is Howland Reed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/163536/54887)

Answer (score 3):

#### Books

Jon didn't take the North in books. That's show only event. In the Books, Reeds did swear allegiance and fealty to Robb Stark when he was proclaimed King in the North:

> Both Reeds were slight of build, slender as swords and scarcely taller
> than Bran himself. They went to one knee before the dais.
>
> “My lords of Stark,” the girl said. “**The years have passed in their
> hundreds and their thousands since my folk first swore their fealty to
> the King in the North. My lord father has sent us here to say the
> words again, for all our people.**” She is looking at me, Bran
> realized. He had to make some answer. “My brother Robb is fighting in
> the south,” he said, “but you can say your words to me, if you like.”
>
> “To Winterfell we pledge the faith of Greywater,” they said together.
> “Hearth and heart and harvest we yield up to you, my lord. Our swords
> and spears and arrows are yours to command. Grant mercy to our weak,
> help to our helpless, and justice to all, and we shall never fail
> you.”
>
> “I swear it by earth and water,” said the boy in green.
>
> “I swear it by bronze and iron,” his sister said.
>
> “We swear it by ice and fire,” they finished together.
> <sub>**ACOK - Bran III**</sub>

So yes they swore fealty to Robb (King in the North) and therefore  to his heirs and successors as well.

---

#### Show

No there is no mention of Reeds swearing fealty to Jon.

Meera returns to Winterfell only after Jon is gone to Dragonstone. Howland Reed himself never leaves his castle. Jojen is dead. So, there is no mention of Reeds swearing fealty explicitly to Jon.

Comment: Surely the fealty to Jon remains from their old fealty to House Stark.

Comment: @Edlothiad Sorry I don't think I understood that? You mean that old fealty to House Stark is extended to Jon? That would be unclear. Bastards do not get to inherit titles in normal circumstances. And fealty to House Stark and fealty to KiTN are different. Reeds came explicitly to swear oaths to Robb when he was crowned, even though House Stark already had fealty of Reeds

Comment: Hmm, that's true, but Jon hasn't seemed to make anyone else swear fealty to him independently has he? It seems like fealty to House Stark extends to KitN? Maybe i'm just misunderstanding

Comment: @Edlothiad Actually Jon seems to [ask Ned Umber and Alys Karstark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iBhXVIv6eg) to pledge allegiance to House Stark and swear an (albeit small) oath to himself ("Will you stand beside **ME**... Now and always?"). So this would mean that all the present lords swear fealty to Jon specifically, and most likely the Starks historically. Plus the Umber/Karstark-Stark alliance has been reformed. And if they chose not to follow Jon because of his (supposed) bastard lineage they could follow Sansa Stark instead, who would inherit the Stark bannermen.

Comment: Ye but they turned against him, the crannogmen never turned against Jon.

Comment: @Edlothiad Correct, they have not sworn fealty to Jon as KitN, but they do owe their allegiance to House Stark as that oath was never broken. As such, the Reed's must follow any orders signed by Princess Sansa Stark but have no obligations to listen to Jon. The other Northern lords however have sworn to Jon as KitN so must abide by his word, as well as that of Sansa as their allegiance to House Stark is also preserved..